# User function to return multiple get_post_meta()

Tags: functions, post-meta

I am trying pass a WP function to a user function, where I can pass a new func argument `$key` for each `post_meta` type here:

functions.php

```
  function my_post_meta($key){
      $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); 
      if ($meta) {
       echo $meta . '<br />';           
     }  
   }
```

page-template.php

Edit:
These functions will be inside a `foreach()` of `get_posts()`.

```
my_post_meta("Author");
my_post_meta("Date") .'customise this meta key';
my_post_meta("Address") .'customise this meta key';
```

Answer (score 1):

The second and third argument to `get_post_meta()` are optional. If not provided-- ie. `get_post_meta($post->ID)`-- you will get an array of all meta for the post.

> If only $id is set it will return all meta values in an associative array.
>
> > http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta#Return_Value

For example:

```
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID); 
var_dump($meta);
```

Comment: Thanks, you put me on the right track but I needed to take it further so not sure if I should mark as the correct answer? I do not have privileges yet anyhow :)

Comment: You may select answer you want, including your own, but this answers the original question better than your own answer, in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

As I wanted to put the `if()` statement into a function - continuing on from s_ha_dum's help, here is my own answer. I included the second argument so as only return the keys I need.

I am passing the `NULL` value to two of my function arguments as way to make them optional as suggested here: [... optional parameter values in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690599/any-way-to-specify-optional-parameter-values-in-php#answer-690639).

functions.php

```
function jd_post_meta($strongstart = NULL, $key, $strongend = NUll){
  global $post;
  $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key);
  if($meta[0]) {
    echo $boldstart.$meta[0].$boldend.'<br />';
  }
}
```

page-template.php

```
jd_post_meta(NULL,'Author',NULL);
jd_post_meta('Translation <strong>','Translator','</strong>');
jd_post_meta(NULL,'Event-date',NULL);
jd_post_meta(NULL,'Event-address',NULL);
```